# How to apply jQuery on Meteor.js

Tags: jquery, meteor

I´ve create a template for meteor.js, what I want is to apply a jQuery effect for an onclick event on tran_button, the idea with the effect is that div associated to button disappear. I don´t get any error through meteor console, or firebug console.

```
Template.tran.events({
    'click .tran_button' : function(){
       $(this._id).slideUp('slow');
     }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the event to the function and get id from event.currentTarget:

```
Template.tran.events({
    'click .tran_button' : function(event){
        $('#' + event.currentTarget.id).slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

$(event.target).slideUp('slow');